# How to consume records from topic using KafkaStream..?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

> How KafkaStream consume messages from topic.

Following is my code :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-app");
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_SERVER_URL + ":" + KAFKA_SERVER_PORT);
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
builder.stream(topic_name).print(null);

streams.start();
```

Comment: `builder.stream(sourceTopicName);
stream.foreach((key, value) -> ...); // for consuming messages; 
stream.to(destinationTopicName); // sending to destination`

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi thank you, But can i use single topic in kafkastream..?

Comment: do you want to consume messages from single topic? and what exactly you want to do on consumer? if so, yes, by using `builder.stream(sourceTopicName).foreach((key, value) -> ...);` and do whatever you want with message key and value. or you could use kstream `process` method

Comment: Any One suggest me how to implement KafkaStream? I'm confused.

Comment: take a look on examples for `KStream` like in https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStreamBuilder

Comment: Run Kafka Streams Demo Application :  https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/quickstart

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi thank u.

Comment: @AftabVirtual thank u, but that demo not understanding to me well.

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi I'm using kafka 2.0 version. In this version kafka stream how to implement.

Comment: You wrote it fine. What's the problem?

Comment: @cricket_007 not getting records

Comment: You can do `builder.stream(topic_name).print()`, however, you can must be actively sending data into the topic

Comment: @cricket_007 Exception: "The method print(Printed<Object,Object>) in the type KStream<Object,Object> is not applicable for the arguments ()"

Comment: Hmm. There is a print method domeegere that shouldn't take arguments. Anyway, did you try any of these examples? https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples

Comment: Maybe you hit: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7326 -- try to use `foreach()` with manual `System.out.println()` instead of `print()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Kafka Streams DSL (Domain Specific Language) is built on top of the Streams Processor API.

It uses low level processor APIs with implementation underneath to read the messages from kafka topics. Here is the detailed architecture:

https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/architecture

Streams DSL is built on top of Processor API. If you deep dive into Processor API, you can see how the functionalities can be implemented and can be called easily with one line of code:

https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html

That's how Stream DSL operations work. While writing a KStream Application, using Streams DSL, most of the operations can be called in few lines of code but underneath it has entire implementation

Here is word count example : 
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.0.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WordCountLambdaExample.java

Initially each operation is converted as **ProcessorNode**. So Reading from a topic is converted into **SourceNode** and writing to a topic is **SinkNode**.
And all the nodes are added into Topology sequentially.
You can see more details in the source code for StreamsBuilder and StreamTask. It will give you idea, how a topology is built and run:

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.0/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StreamTask.java

Below is the KStream Application example for Wordcount. Let's say "wordcount-input" is the input topic and "wordcount-output" is the output topic :

```
final String bootstrapServers = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "localhost:9092";
final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "wordcount-lambda-example"); 
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "wordcount-lambda-example-client");
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
streamsConfiguration.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest"); // add if you want to reset the offset to earliest for each run
final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
final Serde<Long> longSerde = Serdes.Long();
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
final KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream("wordcount-input");
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\W+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
final KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = textLines
  .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(pattern.split(value.toLowerCase())))
  .groupBy((key, word) -> word)
  .count();
// Write the `KTable<String, Long>` to the output topic.
wordCounts.toStream().to("wordcount-output", Produced.with(stringSerde, longSerde));
final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration);

streams.cleanUp();
streams.start();
```

Comment: But how producer and consumer work here. How produce the messages to topic and how consume messages from same topic using KafkaStream.

Comment: Updated the answer, There are SourceNode and SinkNode processor which have their implementation. Have you tried digging into the kafka-streams source code? Though I added some  details above. Hope that is helpful for you

Comment: This doesn't really help the code in the question, it's just pointing at the documentation

Comment: @cricket_007: To my understanding, OP wanted to understand the concepts, how the stream tasks are consuming messesges before talking about offset reset property. That's why there are documentation links :)

Comment: @NishuTayal How can implement Kafka Stream on single Topic is it implement or not..?

Comment: @KailasBiradar : It is already there. you need to call builder.stream("topicName") method

Comment: @NishuTayal using kafka stream _"Kafka Consumer is not safe for multi-threaded access Exception"_ this exception solve..?